# Reformatting array of arrays to nested json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

I'm working in Javascript.

I'm trying to convert an array of arrays into a nested JSON object.

Here is the array of arrays. Each array represents a branch of a tree.

```
    LoL = [["parent", "child1", "grandchild1"],
["parent", "child1", "grandchild2"],
["parent","child2", "grandchild3"]]
```

I need to reformat this data into a nested JSON object, something like:

```
json = {
"name": "parent",
"children": [
    {
     "name": "child1",
      "children": [
         {
          "name": "grandchild1"
         },
         {
           "name": "grandchild2"
         }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "child2"
       "children":[
          {
           "name":"grandchild3"
          }
        ]
    }
]};
```

(essentially trying to turn an array of arrays to match the flare.json found in this project: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/4733217)

What would be the best approach to reformat?

Comment: Once you split the string by `|`, it is the same question. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/u16dnLro/

Comment: @adigna Amazing! Thanks so much for taking the time for putting the fiddle together - it completely solved my problem!